# sqlcmd - problem to connect with sql credentials

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have a SQL database service in Azure with a server name `dummyserver.database.windows.net.`
I have also a database `dummyDB` with user `dummyuser`.

I can connect there providing above parameters and credentials with Azure Data Studio and other DB tools.
But when I try to do the same tith sqlcmd i get an error:

```
sqlcmd -S dummyserver.database.windows.net
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : MAX_PROVS: The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Please try again later.
.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Cannot generate SSPI context.
```

I went through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16
but haven't found any way to connect using login/password
In my case it is not even login issue because I don't get to this point yet.

My error is earlier.
Any hint what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60605405/sql-server-authentication-fails-using-sqlcmd?rq=1

Comment: This might work with MSSQL. I'm using SQL Database service in the Azure. And because I can login there using user and password with other tools, I assume this option is enabled on the Server site